# How to retrieve a string name as an array variable?

Tags: php

I have a question about PHP string and array, I have an array called

```
$profile_name = array();
$str_profile_name = 'profile_name';
```

Now I want to call this array with the help of str_profile_name and push it every time inside a loop, which is like that `array_push($($str_profile_name), $name);`

but it give errors, $name is any string names, It doesn't matter, which matters is that I want to push $name string into the ($profile_name) array, but by using $str_profile_name.

thanks for helping me out.

Comment: `array_push($$str_profile_name, $name);`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @IłyaBursov, your answered worked ;) thanks a bunch, why didn't you make it as answer but rather a comment?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace :

```
array_push($($str_profile_name), $name);
```

by :

```
array_push(${$str_profile_name}, $name);
```

Globally : change `()` by `{}`.